# Jquery need to catch radio button event

Tags: jquery, events, radio-button

I'm trying to write some jquery to catch the event when a radio button is selected.  When I inspect the page, the source looks like this:

```
<input id="ProgTrain_6__5" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$MyResponse$ProgTrain_6" value="ProgTrain_6__5" checked="checked" onclick="clientScriptProgTrain_6_specifyToggleState();" validate="">
```

I've made several attempts like these:

```
$('input[type=radio][name="ProgTrain_row6"]').change(function () {
        alert('hi');
    });

$('input[type=radio][name*=ProgTrain_row6]').click(function ()
$('#ProgTrain_row6').click(function ()

{
    alert('radio button selected');
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        alert("checked");
    }
});


$('#ProgTrain_6__5').click(function ()
$('input[type=radio][name*=ProgTrain_6__5]').click(function ()
{
    alert('radio button selected');
    if ($(this).attr("checked") == "checked") {
        alert("checked");
    }
});


if ($('input[@name=ProgTrain_row6]:radio:checked').length > 0) {
    alert('radio button clicked')
};
```

Please advise.

Comment: do you have a function called `clientScriptProgTrain_6_specifyToggleState()`?

Comment: select with this $("#ProgTrain_6__5")

Comment: You have syntax errors galore -- several of your functions are missing `{}` around the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of jQuery's [ends-with selector `$=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) that allows you to target elements based on the value of specific attributes.

In your case, you could target any elements with a name attribute that ends-with "Prog_Train6" :

```
$('[name=$"ProgTrain_6"]').change(function () {
    alert($(this).is(':checked')? 'Checked!' : 'Unchecked!');
});
```

If you wanted to actually target *any* radio button that was clicked, you could handle this as well using the [`:radio`](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector :

```
$(':radio').change(function(){
    // Some radio button was changed, refer to it using $(this) here...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the change event instead of a click event.  This will then allow events driven by the keyboard or otherwise.  You might also optimize the conditional a bit for the checked property.

```
$('#ProgTrain_6__5').on('change', function() {
  alert('radio button selected');
  if (this.checked) {
    alert("checked");
  }
});
```

An alternative, wrap the inputs in another element then use the wrapper and the input type for the selection:

```
<div class="mywrapper">
  <input id="ProgTrain_6__5" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$MyResponse$ProgTrain_6" value="ProgTrain_6__5" validate="" />
  <input id="ProgTrain_6__6" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl02$MyResponse$ProgTrain_6" value="ProgTrain_6__6" validate="" />
</div>
```

Code:

```
$('.mywrapper').on('change', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
  alert(this.value + ":" + this.id);
});
```